# Is it possible to derive Maxwells equations from geometrical optics?

Tags: optics, hamiltonian-formalism, maxwell-equations, geometric-optics

[Geometrical](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometrical_optics)/[Hamiltonian optics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamiltonian_optics) can be derived as short wavelength limit of Maxwells equation. In doing so one approximates the relativistic wave theory of light with a non-relativistic single particle classical mechanics theory. Now my question is: Can one also go backwards and "derive"  Maxwells equations from Hamiltonian optics?

Comment: I don't think that you can reverse an approximation in general. Let me make a simple example: both $e^{-x}$ and $(1+x)^{-1}$, when approximated to the first order, give $1-x$. However, if I give you $1-x$, how can you tell if it is the approximation of $e^{-x}$ or of $(1+x)^{-1}$?

Comment: You can't, because Maxwell equations are more general and predict wider variety of phenomena than geometrical optics.

Comment: Yes, you can ;-) See my answer below.

Comment: I think that the comments of valerie92 and Blazey are completely right. You cannot derive Maxwell's equation by logical (mathematical) inference from geometrical ray optics which is a drastic simplification of the results of the former.

Comment: @freecharly I'm was very interested in an answer to the question. But after not getting any answer for a week or so I googles a lot and found that paper.  It is from a peer reviewed journal (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Physics_Letters), so I'm not sure why you call that "obscure". I also don't understand why sharing information from that paper is bad. If you have a better answer, please write one.

Comment: @asmaier - I am sorry for having exaggerated in my earlier comment. Physics Letters A is, of course, a recognized journal. The cited article by Pradhan has been cited 9 times. I still think that he did not "derive" Maxwell's equations from geometrical optics which would mean that geometrical optics implies Maxwell's electrodynamics. I deleted this earlier comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The process of deriving a wave equation from geometrical optics is called "wavization". It is similar to Schrödingers derivation of the Schrödinger equation starting from Hamiltonian mechanics. It is described in the book Ghatak and Thyagarajan (1978), Contemporary Optics, Chapter 1.7 . However the derivation in this book only yields a scalar wave equation and not the full system of Maxwells equations.

The full derivation can be found in [Pradhan (1987): "Maxwell's equations from geometrical optics"](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/0375-9601(87)90735-3).

**Update**: In the meantime I found a much better discussion in Marcuse (1972), Light Transmission Optics, Chapter 3.6. The author also mentions that [Eichmann (1971): "Quasi-Geometric Optics of Media with Inhomogeneous Index of Refraction"](https://doi.org/10.1364/JOSA.61.000161) developed a Dirac type of theory of ray optics and showed that the Dirac equation of light rays is equivalent to the time independent Maxwell equations. So it seems to me that Eichmann anticipated Pradhan by 16 years.

Comment: It is known that the Schrödinger did not "derive" his Schrödinger equation from Hamiltonian mechanics. It was only a heuristic plausibility consideration. Similarly, the cited paper of Pradhan does not derive Maxwells equations. He only arrives at them by introducing suitable ad hoc assumptions.

Comment: I think he did. At least there is a whole chapter "The hamiltonian analogy between mechanics and optics" in his paper from 1926: https://people.isy.liu.se/jalar/kurser/QF/references/Schrodinger1926c.pdf Maybe I should not have called that derivation but motivation.

Comment: You are right, it is known that Schrödinger was motivated by this analogy. However, he didn't "derive" the Schrödinger equation from it, because it cannot be derived. It was invented by him and it proved to be successful, just like Newton invented his laws.